# Centered bootstrap navbar

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, center, responsive

I'd like to create a centered bootstrap navbar with logo. Here's how I see it:

[image: point of view]

How can I make that effect?

Comment: Please provide more information: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please provide more information and paste your code

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information.
If you want the logo & menu centered then do:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
   <div class="container">
      //write the code for brand-header / menu here
   </div>
</nav>
```